# Android Repo sync Fatal error

Tags: android, git, android-source, repo

`$ repo sync` for

> Build LMY47V android-5.1.1_r1 Lollipop

results into error:

```
Fetching projects:  62% (302/486)  Fetching project platform/frameworks/base
fatal: Not a git repository: '/home/ashish/askdnx/.repo/projects/frameworks/base.git'
```

The repo sync goes on for sometime and then fails with errors.

What could be a fix for this ? 
Can I use

```
$ git clone https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base.git
```

Comment: You can use git by itself if you just want to pull down a single project - the challenge is that it won't be well integrated with repo for an overall build.  But it could be interesting as a debugging step to try it and see if that also fails.  Beware that frameworks/base is one of the larger pieces of Android so it will take a while.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only solution I found to fix the above problem is to start FRESH.

As per the above post

```
rm -rf ~/.repo/
```

didnt quite remove the files for me. Please try that too. Thanks to @shkschneider for giving that answer. So bascially you have to remove bin folder and the .repo folder manually before you start fresh.

Tips for starting fresh:

USE `repo sync -j1` for sync the Android Source Tree. It takes time but it is the best solution to problems like remote hung up unexpectedly. 
I may be wrong in this. but none of the methods found on the internet helped me.

Answer (score 2):

You should not use `git clone` to checkout Android source code.

Use `repo` all the way:

```
curl https://storage.googleapis.com/git-repo-downloads/repo > repo
chmod a+x repo
repo init -u --config-name https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest -b android-5.1.1_r1
repo sync
```

If that does not work, clean up your repo files:

```
rm -rf ~/.repo/
```

Comment: How can I fix the error then ? 

Not a git repository

Comment: You still get that error after the `repo init` and `repo sync`? Then I would suggest you just clean (remove) your repo files in *~/.repo*.

Comment: Yes. I still get the error. can I do "repo" for specific folders.? I guess 
I the folder frameworks/base.git is having errors. 

I do remember getting a error "FATAL: Unexpected EOF" at remote repository.

Should I report to google? Is it anything worth?

Comment: You can always report to Google to help improve `repo`'s ability to recover from an error. For now you could repose *frameworks/base* entirely and let `repo` sync it back again, starting fresh with a valid repository (but also do this in *~/.repo*, that is what `repo` complains about).

Comment: Repose framworks/base? ... 

Any other temporary fix to the current problem.? Should I use some other build than LMY4V android android-5.1.1_r1?
> fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
> fatal: early EOF

and I am reporting to google

Comment: "Any temporary fix" have you tried what I suggested? `rm -rf ~/.repo/projects/frameworks/base` and `rm -rf frameworks/base`?

Comment: Yes. No change! I am going for a fresh repo.

Answer (score 1):

Find **all** necessary .git files in .repo directory and delete them.
For me, it was working ok